# Excel that allows you to select a cell and go to the corresponding sheet name

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, code

I have the following code for selecting a cell with a specific name and the going to the sheet that is names after that cell.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = Range("A1").Value Then
         ws.Activate
        End If
    Next ws
End If
```

However I would like to do this for cells in column A!  A1-A306 how should i modify the code?

Comment: So you want to go to the sheet where Target.value = the name and the Target is in A1:A306?

Comment: A bit different method, but you could just had hyperlinks to all the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this - but its not doing it by looking at the value of .Address

```
If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A306")) Is Nothing) Then
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = Target.Value Then
         ws.Activate
        End If
    Next ws
End If
```

Comment: Worked Perfect!